# The type requirement [B >: A] for ++ operator in Scala Lists

Tags: scala, covariance, scala-collections, contravariance

I have a basic question regarding the ++ Operator in Scala lists, and the type notation [B >: A].

It is most common to explain this as "Accept any B which is a Superclass of A"

But then I can do something like the below code and invoke `++` using a `class B` (Sprite) which is not superclass of `class A` (Cola).

I understand then scala might be inferring the the closest common ancestor in such a situation, and creating a list of `SoftDrink` objects when `++` is invoked like below.

My question is, where in the API documentation does it state that it is ok to pass a `B` which has a common ancestor with `A` to `++` operator? `[B >: A]` seems quite straightforward in the contractual demand that `B` is a superclass of `A` and not anything about a common ancestor.

```
abstract class Drink
abstract class SoftDrink() extends Drink
abstract class Juice() extends Drink
case class Cola() extends SoftDrink
case class Sprite() extends SoftDrink

scala> val al = List(Cola(), Cola())
al: List[Cola] = List(Cola(), Cola())

scala> val bl = List(Sprite())
bl: List[Sprite] = List(Sprite())

scala> val cl = al ++ bl
cl: List[SoftDrink with Product with Serializable] = List(Cola(), 
Cola(), Sprite())
```

Answer (score 3):

> where in the API documentation does it state that it is ok to pass a B which has a common ancestor with A to ++ operator?

It doesn't need to, because that falls out of the definition of lower type bounds. The closest super type of `Sprite` and `Cola` is `SoftDrink`, thus satisfying the requirement for the compiler.

You are right in that it may not be immediately intuitive that the compiler helps search for a common ancestor of the two types, but it still falls into the criteria of the definition.

The relevant part of the Scala specification which points this out is [Conformance](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#conformance)

Answer (score 1):

Scala docs, List ++

> `def ++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]`
>
> Returns a new list containing the elements from the left hand operand followed by
>   the elements from the right hand operand. The element type of the list
>   is the most specific superclass encompassing the element types of the
>   two operands.